# Equivalent to float AtomicAdd in WebGPU

Tags: javascript, compute-shader, webgpu

We have an OpenGL solver. Given a list of many items, each has a coordinate and a **float** value. We run a compute shader of the size of those items that does the computation and adds the value to the existing values in the **float** image using the function `imageAtomicAdd` and the float extension. This way, the addition is guaranteed just in case 2 items happen to have the same coordinate value simultaneously.

Now, we need to move it to WebGPU using js. I tried looking for an atomic add function on **float** texture/buffer but with limited success. So, the code currently is like this

```
outputBuffer[coords] += floatValue; // TODO: fix!!
```

As expected, it works but without guarantees. Some pixels are flickering depending on which thread worked first.

So, how can I do it safely? either using a function like `atomicAdd` or something similar to CUDA's sync threads/barriers?

Comment: you could use [fixed point math](https://www.google.com/search?q=fixed+point+math) if it suits your needs.